# Email confirmation

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to find email has been delivered in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141294/how-to-find-email-has-been-delivered-in-android)

How do I confirm that an email has been delivered when sending email with android?

Comment: Send another email to the user asking them to write back if they got the first email?

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard way to confirm that email has been delivered. Also, "delivered" does not mean "read".

This can be done if either:

1. Both users are on the same custom email system (like Exchange) that supports this non-standard functionality.
2. One of non-standard ways of read confirmations is used:

   a. Mail is stored on server and only a (scrambled) URL to this message is sent in email. User needs to follow this URL to see the message. This is how email marketing works.

   b. Hidden image is stored in email. This image points to an URL on your server. This does not work as most modern email readers do not show images by default.